# How can I update a VSTO excel add-in with a new version?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015, vsto, office-interop

I just made a new C# VSTO Excel COM Add-in. I deployed it by just going to build->publish, and created the Setup, VSTO Deployment Manifest, and the application files folder. I then copied it over to the user's machine and installed it, easy peezy.

I recently made a few changes to the add-in code and would like to update it on the user's machine. To do this, can I just repeat the process? When I run the setup of the newer version will it automatically update what needs to be update nice and clean?

Just wanted to ask before I potentially mess something up because in my experience these VSTO add-ins can be picky (but perhaps that's just been my lack of know-how).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your add-in auto-updated you need to publish it to any web server and then install it from there. Then if required you may publish an update. Your add-in will be automatically updated. Read more about the ClickOnce installer in the [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019#Publish) article.